# Read more bytes than allocated

Tags: c#, metadata, id3

I am facing a problem with my ID3v1 metadata reader. When I go to read, say the album of a band, and it exceeds the 30 bytes allocated for it, it cuts off the rest of the title.

```
Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer, 63, 30);
```

So I read 30 of the bytes but what if it exceeds? Can I modify it to read more? Or store it somewhere else when it reaches more than 30?

i.e:

`echoes silence patience & gra`

instead of

`echoes silence patience & grace`

Comment: your metadata reader or 3th party? if so which??

Comment: It is my own. Reading bytes of the mp3.

Comment: ID3v1 specs tell that artist, song and title are 30 chars. You can read more, but no more than 30 are written. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3

Answer (score 1):

For ID3V1, the `title`, `artist`, and `album` fields are limited to 30 bytes. There's no space for more: if you read past the end, you'll just end up reading part of the next field.

ID3V2 allows for more and longer fields, but it's almost entirely unlike ID3V1.

Comment: I've looked into ID3v2 and it looks a lot more complex than v1. Do you know of any good sites on ID3v2? I am not interested in 3rd party.

Comment: If you're determined to roll your own, I'd start with the specs anyway. Anything else is just going to be someone else's interpretation of them, anyway. http://id3.org/Developer%20Information